# Undefined property: stdClass::$column_name problem for run laravel project

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

any body have resolve for this issue ?

configuration :
php7.1
laravel 5.3
mysql 8.0.22

```
ErrorException in MySqlProcessor.php line 18:
Undefined property: stdClass::$column_name
```

Answer (score -1):

according to  [Specify lower case column_name](https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/21037) , MySqlProcessor.php line 18 return $r->column_name assume your column name is column_name, but maybe the table you queried have COLUMN_NAME or camelcase? (i dont have any COLUMN_NAME but this question too, I guess it caused by mysql8).

so find if you have COLUMN_NAME first, if not, I think mysql5 will work properly, i dont like it though